# How would do I get the paddle to hit the ball up and back into the air?

Tags: javascript, game-physics

```
var BALL_RADIUS = 15;
var STARTING_Y = 0;
var STARTING_X = 150;
var GRAVITY_ACCELERATION = 2;
var ANIMATION_DELAY = 60;

var square;
var paddlelocationX = 100;
var paddlelocationY = 410;
var score = 0;

var ball;
var velocityX;
var velocityY;




function start(){
    var start = println("Welcome to the game Ping Ball ");
    createBall();
    initializeVelocity();
    startSimulation();

    square = new Rectangle(90, 10);
    //I messed around with the Y-Variable a slight bit
    square.setPosition(paddlelocationX, paddlelocationY);
    add(square);
    keyDownMethod(keyDown);

}


function createBall(){
    ball = new Circle(BALL_RADIUS);
    ball.setPosition(STARTING_X, STARTING_Y);
    add(ball);
}


function initializeVelocity(){
    velocityX = Randomizer.nextFloat(0, 5);
    velocityY = 0;
}


function startSimulation(){
    setTimer(moveBall, ANIMATION_DELAY);
}


function moveBall(){
    ball.move(velocityX, velocityY);
    
    checkForBounce();
    
    velocityY += GRAVITY_ACCELERATION;
}


function checkForBounce(){
    var radius = ball.getRadius();
    if(ball.getX() + radius >= getWidth()){
        velocityX *= -1;
        ball.setPosition(getWidth() - radius, ball.getY());
    }
    if(ball.getX() - radius <= 0){
        velocityX *= -1;
        ball.setPosition(radius, ball.getY());
    }
    if(ball.getY() + radius >= getHeight()){
        velocityY = -1 * Math.abs(velocityY);
        ball.setPosition(ball.getX(), getHeight() - radius);
    }
    if(ball.getY() - radius <= 0){
        velocityY *= -1;
        ball.setPosition(ball.getX(), radius);
    }
    if(ball.getY() >= 460){
        ball.setPosition(ball.getX(), 500);
    }
}


function keyDown(e){
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        square.move(-10, 0);
    }
    
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        square.move(10, 0);
    }
}

var txt = new Text("Current Score:"+score,"10pt Ariel");
txt.setPosition(312,13);
add(txt);
```

So far this is my code made. I'm really struggling to find out where I can implement something to get the ball to hit the paddle and I don't know where to start. Like, I know I that if the ball's center comes near the paddle then I know I need the ball to bounce up from there and keep on bouncing back in forth just like that.

I don't know if I need to add that conditionality under my "checkBounce" function or make a new one.

Thanks for anyone who can help <3

Also, the code mainly only works in CodeHS (Javascript Graphics)

Comment: Can you give background about the problem ? Welcome to stackoverflow, Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, Yes I can.

I'm making a game as a self-organized project. This game is basically a self-playing pong pretty much. And the user is supposed to keep up with the ball by using the paddle, but the paddle doesn't work and doesn't hit the ball. You specifically have to use  the CodeHS IDE (Javascript Graphics) to code this out, incase you're wondering